# RegEx pattern to detect two consecutive numbers followed by at the most 9 characters?

Tags: java, regex

How can I create a regex that detects any string starting with two consecutive numbers followed by at the most nine consecutive characters with a hyphen symbol in java regex? For instance:

```
nnccccccccc-nnccccccccc
```

or

```
nncccccc-nnccccccccc
```

or

```
nnccccccc-nncccccccc
```

Where `n` represents a number from 0 to 1 and `c` a letter character.

So far I tried this: https://regex101.com/r/a1eJvY/2.

Comment: You mention *Where `n` represents a number from 0 to 1* however what you want to match seems to represent numbers from *0 to 9*. Which one is correct?

Comment: is regex a must? if not I would rather try to parse the dates... what would you do if there is a 30february? or 60march?

Comment: reading your question again... how can the accepted answer be **the** answer of your question? ;-) 2 consecutive numbers followed by at most 9 characters with a hyphen symbol... the consecutive numbers must be 0 or 1.... not that i criticize the answer... I rather criticize the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for your matches:

```
^\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{1,9}-\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{1,9}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a1eJvY/3)

If you are using `.matches()` method then `^` and `$` are not needed.

- `\d{1,2}`: Match 1 or 2 digits
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,9}`: Match 1 to 9 English letters
- `-`: Match literal hyphen

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{0,9})-(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{0,9})$` example: https://regex101.com/r/A2wiHH/2.

This will match the string as described below:

1. The beginning of your string
2. `2` decimals
3. `0-9` characters
4. `-`,
5. `2` decimals again,
6. `0-9` characters again
7. The end of your string

Comment: This will also match `01april-01april-`. Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483221/548225) to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that "nn" and no one letter char is accepted, so, for a single sequence:

```
[0,1]{2}\D{0,9}
```

Explaination:

`[0,1]{2}` --> Accept only 0 and 1 as number exactly two times;

`\D{0,9}` --> Accept 0 to 9 generic number.

Edit: you said

> Where n represents a number from 0 to 1

but if `22may` is accepted, you want number from 0 to 9, so you have to use `\d`

```
\d{2}\D{0,9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[0-1] {2}+ [a-z] {9}. +-